# Favorites cart with React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Bonjour stackoverflow, I made a Favorites component to add movies that I get through an API. I used Redux to add movies to the Favorites component but I'm just getting an integer for the moment. I would like to retrieve all the informations about the added movie (title, description, photos etc..) and display it in my Favorites component.

**So here is my Favorites component that retrieves favorites movies:**

```
<div>
        <Badge className={classes.badgeFav} color="secondary" badgeContent={this.props.movieReducer.movies.length}>
          <Button
            onClick={this.handleClickOpen}
            target="_blank"
            className={classes.navLink}
          >
            <Favorite className={classes.icons} /> Favorites
          </Button>
          </Badge>
          <Dialog
            open={this.state.open}
            TransitionComponent={Transition}
            keepMounted
            onClose={this.handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
          >
            <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-slide-title">My Favorites</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
              <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-slide-description">
                {this.props.movieReducer.movies.length} movie(s)
              </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={this.handleClose} className={classes.navLinkMod}>
                Close
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
      </div>
```

With Redux at the end:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({

});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state
})
```

**And my component that add movie to Favorite Component (I have removed some code for more understanding):**
(For the moment it sends an integer (onClick={() => addMovie(1)}) )

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { addMovie } = this.props;
    const theMovies = this.state.films.map((film) => {
      return(
        <Grid key={film.id} item xs={6} sm={6} md={3} lg={3}>
          <Card className='container-card-poster'>
                <figcaption className='fig-caption'>
                  <h4 className={classes.titleOverlay}>{film.title}</h4>
                </figcaption>
                  <Tooltip 
                    TransitionComponent={Zoom}
                    id="Add to favorite"
                    title={<p>Add to favorite</p>}
                    placement={window.innerWidth > 959 ? "top" : "top"}
                  >
                    <Favorite onClick={() => addMovie(1)} className={classes.iconsHoverFav} />
                  </Tooltip>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
```

With Redux at the end:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addMovie: (movie) => dispatch(addMovie(movie))
});
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state
})
TopFilms.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object
};
```

I don't know how to get all the information when adding a movie so if someone can help me, that would be great!

Have a nice day everyone.

Comment: Not sure that I understand which `information` are you talking about, could you explain, please?

Comment: Hello @NazarLitvin and sorry for the delay. I'm talking about the movie's informations like title, date, overview, pictures etc.. For the moment all I can get is an integer.  I pass the function addMovie in my "onClick" with an integer as value. I would like to replace this integer by the information of the movie but I don't know how to do it..

Comment: From what I understood from your code you can just replace call `addMovie` with `film` instead of `1` here `onClick={() => addMovie(1)}`. But It's not clear for me why do you store `films` in your component state. I will update my answer with code samples a bit later, so probably it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help @NazarLitvin , I have replaced call `addMovie` with `film` instead of `1` and I made a `.map` in my Favorites component to display informations of the movie added. I don't know if you're talking about the same thing but I store `films` in my component state to display all the films I get by the API with a `.map`

Comment: Could I ask you to share a piece of code which makes this API request?

Comment: Hi @NazarLitvin, Sorry for the wait. Here is the piece of code which makes the API request: `getFilms(){
    const { page } = this.state;
    const { currentCategory } = this.state;
    Axios.get(`${baseUrlDiscover}&page=${page}&with_genres=${currentCategory}`)
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        films: response.data.results,
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      this.setState({
        films: [],
      })
    })
  }`

Answer (score 1):

It's very useful to store your data in Redux normalized. So you should have a reducer which will store movies in JS object when key is a movie ID and value a movie itself. So than you can make a reducer for favourutes movies, which will simply store their ID.

So in this case your movies will be stored as:

```
{
  1: { name: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  2: { name: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  3: { name: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 }
}
```

Favorites as:

```
[ 1, 3 ]
```

And when you have to render a component with a favourite movie you can take it by id.